# R: gsub punctuation characters only at the end of the string

Tags: r, regex, gsub

I have string like 'aa;a' 'aa;' and I need to delete ';' (or any other punctuation character) only if the string ends with it. If it starts with it or contains it in the middle, I do not want to delete it.

The below line results in the deleting of the ';'

```
gsub("(^.*)[[:punct:]]","",'a;a')
```

Comment: Just to clear things, the result of `a;a;` would be `aa` but the result of `a;a` would be `a;a`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We can specify the metacharacter `$` after the `[[:punct:]]` to signify the end of the string, thus it matches a punctuation at the end of the string and replace it with blank (`""`)

```
sub("[[:punct:]]$","",c('a;a', 'aa;'))
#[1] "a;a" "aa"
```

Note that instead of `gsub` (global substitution), the `sub` is used to match and replace only for a single instance.